# Error calling Solr Cloud Index within Hadoop Job

Tags: hadoop, solr, solrj, emr

My goal is to run an elastic map reduce job that queries a Solr index in the map phase and writes the result to S3. Solr and Hadoop worked fine together when building a Solr index within a Hadoop job (ie writing to Solr index). When I run the a job to query a Solr index I get an error when trying to initiate the Solr client. I suspect that there's a dependency issue between Hadoop and Solr, I recall they both use different versions of http clients and the error is a method not found issue. Here's the stack trace

```
2013-07-24 03:17:47,082 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child (main): Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault()Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;
at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setMaxConnections(HttpClientUtil.java:179)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:33)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.configureClient(HttpClientUtil.java:115)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:105)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:154)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:127)
```

Comment: Did you add the solr dependent jars to Hadoop?

Comment: I assume we're using the default hadoop jar on EMR and we run the job with our own packaged jar file. I check the jar tvf on it and strangely it contained the class with the method it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this opt did the trick

--args -s,mapreduce.user.classpath.first=true

Using the user defined classpath worked out the dependency issue between the hadoop and solr jar